# How to implement incremental load using insert/update instead of merge in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have implemented incremental load using merge, but I want using insert/update. Please help.

This is the stored procedure for the merge method. The stored procedure below loads data from source only when there are new records inserted, else it will discard. Updates only when there are updates in the record.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOAD_DIM_ADDRESS]
AS
BEGIN 
    MERGE [VINCE_RETAIL_TEST].[dbo].[DIM_ADDRESS] AS T
    USING (SELECT 
               '1' as [COMPANY_KEY],
               C.[CUSTOMER_KEY],
               A.[ADDRESS_ID], A.[ADDRESS_TYPE],
               '0' as [REGION_KEY],
               '-1' as [COUNTRY_KEY],
               '-1' as [STATE_KEY],
               A.[CITY], A.[POSTAL_CODE]      
           FROM 
               [AX_STAGING].[dbo].[DIM_ADDRESS] A 
           INNER JOIN 
               [VINCE_RETAIL_TEST].[dbo].[DIM_CUSTOMER] C ON C.[CUSTOMER_ID] = A.[CUSTOMER_ID] 
                                                          AND C.[ADDRESS_ID] = A.[ADDRESS_ID]) AS S
    ON (T.[ADDRESS_ID] = S.[ADDRESS_ID] AND T.[ADDRESS_TYPE]=S.[ADDRESS_TYPE])

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET 
           T.[COMPANY_KEY] = S.[COMPANY_KEY],
           T.[CUSTOMER_KEY] = S.[CUSTOMER_KEY],
           T.[ADDRESS_ID] = S.[ADDRESS_ID],
           T.[ADDRESS_TYPE] = S.[ADDRESS_TYPE], 
           T.[REGION_KEY] = S.[REGION_KEY],
           T.[COUNTRY_KEY] = S.[COUNTRY_KEY],
           T.[STATE_KEY] = S.[STATE_KEY],
           T.[CITY] = S.[CITY],
           T.[POSTAL_CODE] = S.[POSTAL_CODE]

 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT ([COMPANY_KEY], [CUSTOMER_KEY], [ADDRESS_ID], [ADDRESS_TYPE],
                [REGION_KEY], [COUNTRY_KEY], [STATE_KEY], [CITY],
                [POSTAL_CODE])
        VALUES (S.[COMPANY_KEY], S.[CUSTOMER_KEY], S.[ADDRESS_ID], S.[ADDRESS_TYPE],
                S.[REGION_KEY], S.[COUNTRY_KEY], S.[STATE_KEY], S.[CITY],
                S.[POSTAL_CODE]);
  END
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate when to use INSERT, when to use UPDATE. So for example, only when `(S.[ADDRESS_ID], S.[ADDRESS_TYPE])` does not exist in the target table, then do the INSERT. The code is listed. Similarly you can write the UPDATE part as a practice. :)

```
INSERT  [VINCE_RETAIL_TEST].[dbo].[DIM_ADDRESS] 
               ([COMPANY_KEY], [CUSTOMER_KEY], [ADDRESS_ID], [ADDRESS_TYPE],
                [REGION_KEY], [COUNTRY_KEY], [STATE_KEY], [CITY],
                [POSTAL_CODE])
SELECT  S.[COMPANY_KEY], S.[CUSTOMER_KEY], S.[ADDRESS_ID], S.[ADDRESS_TYPE],
        S.[REGION_KEY], S.[COUNTRY_KEY], S.[STATE_KEY], S.[CITY],
        S.[POSTAL_CODE]
FROM    (SELECT 
               '1' as [COMPANY_KEY],
               C.[CUSTOMER_KEY],
               A.[ADDRESS_ID], A.[ADDRESS_TYPE],
               '0' as [REGION_KEY],
               '-1' as [COUNTRY_KEY],
               '-1' as [STATE_KEY],
               A.[CITY], A.[POSTAL_CODE]      
        FROM 
               [AX_STAGING].[dbo].[DIM_ADDRESS] A 
        INNER JOIN 
               [VINCE_RETAIL_TEST].[dbo].[DIM_CUSTOMER] C ON C.[CUSTOMER_ID] = A.[CUSTOMER_ID] 
                                                          AND C.[ADDRESS_ID] = A.[ADDRESS_ID]) AS S
WHERE   (S.[ADDRESS_ID], S.[ADDRESS_TYPE]) NOT IN (SELECT [ADDRESS_ID],[ADDRESS_TYPE] FROM [VINCE_RETAIL_TEST].[dbo].[DIM_ADDRESS])
```

Comment: Thanks Henry!! It helped alot